# Extract a link from Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm quite new to programming.
I'm trying to extract a link using Beautiful Soup.

Here's an excerpt of my soup. What I'm trying to extract is the link after "href". However, nothing I've been trying has been working.

```
></style><div id="taw"><div></div><div style="padding:0 20px"><div class="med"><div class="card" id="msg_box" style="display:none"><p class="card-section w4VK3c"><span><span class="gL9Hy" id="srfm"></span>&nbsp;<a class="gL9Hy" id="srfl"></a><br></span><span id="sif"><span class="spell_orig" id="sifm"></span>&nbsp;<a class="spell_orig" id="sifl"></a><br></span></p></div></div></div><div id="tvcap"></div></div><div class="med" id="res" role="main"><div id="topstuff"></div><div id="search"><div data-ved="0ahUKEwj9irrRpr_fAhXh24MKHSUTB_cQGggp"><!--a--><h1 class="bNg8Rb">Search Results</h1><div data-async-context="query:Canada%20Pays%20Off%20Entire%20Federal%20Debt%20One%20Day%20After%20Marijuana%20Legalization" id="ires"><div eid="UGYkXP2iEeG3jwSlppy4Dw" id="rso"><div class="bkWMgd"><h2 class="bNg8Rb">Web results</h2><div class="srg"><div class="g"><!--m--><div data-hveid="CAMQAA" data-ved="2ahUKEwj9irrRpr_fAhXh24MKHSUTB_cQFSgAMAB6BAgDEAA"><div class="rc"><div class="r"><a href="https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/canada-marijuana-federal-debt/" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/canada-marijuana-federal-debt/&amp;ved=2ahUKEwj9irrRpr_fAhXh24MKHSUTB_cQFjAAegQIAxAB"><h3 class="LC20lb">Did Canada Pay Off Entire Federal Debt One Day After Marijuana ...</h3><br><div style="display:inline-block" class="TbwUpd"><cite class="iUh30 bc">https://www.snopes.com &rsaquo; Fact Check &rsaquo; Junk News</cite></div></a><span><div class="action-menu ab_ctl"><a class="GHDvEf ab_button" href="#" id="am-b0" aria-label="Result Options" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" jsaction="m.tdd;keydown:m.hbke;keypress:m.mskpe" data-ved="2ahUKEwj9irrRpr_fAhXh24MKHSUTB_cQ7B0wAHoECAMQAw"><span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span></a><div class="action-menu-panel ab_dropdown" role="menu" tabindex="-1" >
```

My idea was:

```
    for link in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'r'}):
    link = link.get('href')
```

Comment: Can you give a complete section of your html?

Comment: @J...S I added some more if that helps. Also, it is the source code of the results page from googling "Canada Pays Off Entire Federal Debt One Day After Marijuana Legalization" (I'm making a fact checker). I'm trying to get the Snopes link.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, 'html.parser')
soup.find("div", class_="r").a['href']
```

since there is only one `<div>` of class `"r"` and where `html_string` is the html source as a Python string.

[`find()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) is used with `class_` parameter to find the `<div>` of class `"r"`. Then its child `<a>`'s `href` attribute is accessed.

So the output would be

```
https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/canada-marijuana-federal-debt/
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but it is still not working for me. If I display the "soup" on my website, the classes change. Maybe that's the problem, using the wrong classes.

Comment: @wheatcracker You mean class name "r" changes?

Comment: Yes. If I display it on my website it looks like `div class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/canada-marijuana-federal-debt/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiI5LuOub_fAhUKyYMKHd7XAdMQFggUMAA&amp;usg=AOvVaw282T4CJxbAty113wMjjdNR">Did <b>Canada Pay Off Entire Federal Debt One Day After Marijuana</b> ...</a>`

Comment: So I guess "r" doesn't change but "h3" is new. That hasn't been working either though.

Comment: @wheatcracker Does `soup.find(class_="r").a['href']` work?

Comment: Update! Just tried it with some editing, and it looks like it is working. Final verdict: `for link in soup.find("h3", class_="r"):
  item = link.get('href')`

Comment: Both yours and mine appear to work. I'll probably stick with yours because it's simpler. Thanks!